# How to record voice and store them to firebase storage in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage, voice-recording

I'm trying to record voice and upload it to the firebase storage.
but unable to record record.
for record voice I'm using [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) plugin.
and unable to recognise, in which variable voice is stored.Actually I have copied this code from the plugin example and paste into my project.

but when I press button `startRecorder()` to record voice   ,timer text does not get changed means recording is not getting started.
Because getting exception `Audio session is not open`

```
String _recorderTxt = '00:00:00';
```

Record voice:

```
void startRecorder() async {
    try {
      // Request Microphone permission if needed
      if (!kIsWeb){
        var status = (await Permissions.cameraAndMicrophonePermissionsGranted()) ;
        // Permission.
        // .microphone.request();
          if (status==false){
            throw RecordingPermissionException("Microphone permission not granted");
          }
      }
      String path = '';
      if (!kIsWeb){
        Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        path = '${tempDir.path}/flutter_sound${ext[_codec.index]}';
      } else{
        path = '_flutter_sound${ext[_codec.index]}';
      }

        await recorderModule.startRecorder
        (
          toFile: path,
          codec: _codec,
          bitRate: 8000,
          numChannels: 1,
          sampleRate: SAMPLE_RATE,
        );
     
      print('startRecorder');

      _recorderSubscription = recorderModule.onProgress.listen((e) {
        if (e != null && e.duration != null) {
          DateTime date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
              e.duration.inMilliseconds,
              isUtc: true);
          String txt = DateFormat('mm:ss:SS', 'en_GB').format(date);

          this.setState(() {
            _recorderTxt = txt.substring(0, 8);
            _dbLevel = e.decibels;
          });
        }
      });

      this.setState(() {
        this._isRecording = true;
        this._path[_codec.index] = path;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      print('startRecorder error: $err');
      setState(() {
        stopRecorder();
        this._isRecording = false;
        cancelRecordingDataSubscription();
        cancelRecorderSubscriptions();
      });
    }
  }
```

Showing timer when voice recording get started:

```
  Container(
     alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
     margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0, bottom: 16.0),
     child: Text(
      "${this._recorderTxt}",
        style: TextStyle(
           fontSize: 35.0,
           color: Colors.black,
        ),
     ),
   ),
```

Store voice to firebase storage:

```
Future<String> uploadAudioToStorage(File audioFile) async {
  try {
   
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('chatAudios/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(audioFile, StorageMetadata(contentType: 'audio/wav')); 
    //  Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.onComplete).uploadSessionUri;
    var downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
      final String url = await downloadUrl;


  print("url:$url");
  return  url;

  } catch (error) {
    print("error$error");
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to describe what you've done to debug this code, and how it isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: In that case it sounds like the problem has nothing to do with storing the recorded data in Firebase yet. I *highly* recommend isolating the problem in as few technologies (and as  little code) as possible, to increase the chances that someone with the right knowledge can/will help. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

you have to open an audio session by writing following code
player.openAudioSession();